# Snake Game Win forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Ive been trying to create a snake game using win forms and ive been having trouble with moving my button tool with event handling using the arrow keys. it would be very helpful if someone could explain to me how make it work

Comment: Edit your question to show the code of your current attempt.

Comment: What is a "button tool"?

Answer (score 1):

From the very limited information you've provided, generally the approach should be to handle the KeyDown event of the Form containing your game. While the form has focus, this event will be raised whenever a key is pressed, at the time it's pressed. (the KeyPress event requires the key to be pressed and released before it is raised; the same action also raises a combination of KeyDown and KeyUp).

When handling the KeyDown event, examine the KeyData property of the KeyEventArgs. That property (read-only) is a flagged enumeration (meaning it can have a combination of the available values). You need to see if one or more of the following are pressed: Keys.Up, Keys.Down, Keys.Left, and Keys.Right. These are the arrow keys. You may also allow the user to use the numpad keys 8, 2, 4, and 6 respectively, which have different Keys enum values. If KeyData has one of these, change the direction the snake is moving, and also set the Handled property of the KeyEventArgs to true, which will tell any other code that responds to the key press not to proceed. This will prevent default behaviors associated with the arrow keys from causing problems.

Understand that the user may press multiple arrow keys. If those keys are in opposite directions, or you don't allow movement in one direction, you will need to decide how to handle this situation. The simple solution is to do nothing. The more complex solution is to track which arrow keys are currently pressed, and if multiple ones are pressed, listen for a KeyUp event that will tell you when one or more has been released, and only change direction when one key is currently pressed.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of information im pretty new here but thank you for your help and il examine it and try to figure out how to handle the project